# Adding multiple data level fields in a bar graph

Tags: excel, graph, excel-2010, bar-chart

I have plotted bar graph but I want the data levels on it not the value of the bar itself but a different set of values (probably from a set of values from a different column). Can I do this in a single step where I can choose which set of values I want to show in the bar graph?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, right-click on the Y-axis, press "Format axis..." and in the axis options you are able to make then necessary amendments. For example, set your minimum/maximum values and/or step units (say, your original values range from 0 to 800. By pressing fixed option button in minimum, you could set it from 0 to 100; and maximum from 800 to 1000).